# How can i prevent page refresh (reload) while pressing login button in asp.net mvc identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, identity

So folks, i just created a `_Login` partial instead of `Login` view and rendered that partial view in my _Layout. The partial view is shown in a `Modal`, until yet everything seems OK! But whenever i just click the Login (Sign In) button the page reloads and nothing happens although i expect an error like the E-mail field cannot be empty or the user does not exist but surprisingly nothing happens and the page refreshes. 
Here is the code for the `_Login` partial.

```
@model Hire.af.WebUI.Models.LoginViewModel

<div class="modal-body">
    <!--Social Media Login Links-->
    <div class="form-group row login-socical">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="button_socical fb">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"> </i>
                <em class="fa-facebook-square">Login with Facebook</em>
            </div>
            <div class="button_socical gg">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"> </i>
                <em class="fa-google-plus">Login with Google</em>
            </div>
            <div class="button_socical linkedin">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"> </i>
                <em class="fa-linkedin-square">Login with LinkedIn</em>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Login Form-->
    <form class="noo-ajax-login-form form-horizontal">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "log form-control", @placeholder="Email OR Username" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "pwd form-control", @placeholder="Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <!--Remember Me Checkbox-->
                <div class="form-actions form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                    <div class="login-form-links">
                        <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Forgot Password?</a></span>
                        <span>
                            Don't have an account yet?
                            <a href="#" class="member-register-link" data-rel="registerModal">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Register Now", "Register") <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
            </p>*@
        }


    </form>
</div>
```

and below is how i rendered this partial in my _Layout.

```
<div class="memberModalLogin modal fade" id="userloginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-member">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                </div>
                <!--Login Partial Goes Here-->
                @Html.Partial("_Login")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested forms which is invalid html and not supported.  Remove the outer form from your partial view

```cs
<form class="noo-ajax-login-form form-horizontal"> // remove this and its closing tag
    @using (Html.BeginForm(....
```